# Replaced front brakes and "AWD temporarily disabled" light coming on

Tags: ford, brakes, awd, anti-seize, edge

My son replaced the front brake pads and rotors on my 2016 Ford Edge today. Afterwards I went for a drive and could smell a very strong "chemical" smell and the wrench light came on, then went off and a few minutes later the "AWD Temp Disabled" light came on a few times. Could this have been caused from him using anti seize when removing the old rotors etc? Possibly from a sensor?

Answer (score 7):

I very much doubt that using anti-seize would have caused this but your suspicion about the ABS sensor is likely right on target.

It's possible you disconnected and neglected to reconnect the sensor on one of the wheels or damaged one of them somehow.

I'd check both sides to make sure that both wheel sensors are properly installed and connected and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to jwh20's correct answer, I'd like to add that if the brake job involved removal of very rusty parts, especially with banging, grinding or cutting, it's possible that chips and flakes of magnetic rust particles are now coating one or more of the wheel speed sensors.

Wheel speed sensors contain a magnet, and if rust particles stick to them, this can greatly weaken the signal picked up from the tone ring. The car's computer would think that one or more wheel is not turning properly, so it might not attempt to engage AWD.

The remedy is to blow the magnetic coating off the sensor with compressed air.